# mercurial command to get the total number of lines of code

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for a mercurial command to get the total number of lines of code in a repository.
I'm sure there's a way to do this without extensions.

Thanks

Comment: You're sure as in you've used it before and forgotten or sure as in you expect it to be there?

Comment: No. I haven't used mercurial before.

Comment: I don't think there is a way without extensions.

Comment: omg it's used to manipulate lines of code and it's not even able to count them.

Comment: Mercurial doesn't manipulate the code. It manages file versioning.

Comment: Well, not by manipulating it. To do that it would need to understand what language your code is written in. It would also need to understand that to give you a worthwhile LoC count.

Comment: @Adam - post an Answer, let us up vote you!

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley I don't actually have any useful answer other than it isn't in Mercurial by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
hg cat glob:** | wc --lines
```

it will include any binary files, but you shouldn't store those anyway. :)

cat will take a -r parameter if you want to count some revision other than the one currently checked out.

Comment: It's worth noting this would just count lines in files, not necessarily a worthwhile lines **of code** count.

Answer (score 3):

The bundled [churn](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension) extension gives you a list of the Lines of Code changed by each author. I suspect this is what you were thinking of, as there's no functionality to do it without extensions.